# More than one "status item" in Statusbar

Tags: wpf, prism, statusbar

I want to manage more than one status in the statusbar. 
I thought about to binding `StatusbarItem`s to the statusbar:

---

| Status1 =======80% | Status3 ==== 40% | Status2 ======= 99%|  |

---

If one `StatusbarItem` reaches 100 %, it should be kicked out of the bar.

How to manage the status values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have an `ObservableCollection<StatusItem>`.

`StatusItem` is a class that represents each status you want to display, and contains appropriate members that implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then you can simply create a data template for a StatusItem that binds to the percent complete value and it will automatically get updated.

Comment: hi, thx. But how to manage that. Is there a service or something like that?